# How can I sandbox Python so one project may not break my other projects?

Tags: python, sandbox

I'm wondering how to set up a sandbox for a Python project of mine with the intention of limiting  libraries updates but most importantly, anything I do in this project should not break any of my other projects I have. I want an isolated environment really where I can test my untested code and know for sure it won't disrupt anything.

I've read around and found 2 options, PySandbox and PyPy's Sandbox but have no idea how to begin or if these are even the best option. I don't want to just blacklist keywords, I just want a safe and stable environment to test in.

Are there any good documents that people are aware of or perhaps any tips from someone who has done this recently?

I'm guessing that it's fairly straightforward to setup? I understand that this may depend on the nature of the project though.

Comment: Are virtual environments not sufficient?

Comment: Link to virtual environment docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html

Comment: Do you simply require virtualenv? https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/virtualenvs/   There's also always the possibility of running Python from a flash-drive, which would also be in it's own environment.

Comment: jumping on the virtual environments chain: conda is another way of managing them: https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html

Comment: Ah yes, that looks to be what I'm after, I'll have a read through. Cheers